# SQL Server 2012 Installation Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I been trying to install SQL Server 2012 on Windows 7 SP1 32 bit.

Logged in as Administrator and launched setup.

Everything installs fine but SQL Server DB Services fails with following error while

One or more command-line switches were invalid

and current file which it was reading was : sql_config_repair_loc_wmi_provider_cpu32_1033

and in log its says:

> The SQL server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured.  Only from successful installations can be repaired.  To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.

Comment: Have you uninstalled it completely and done a fresh install as the log suggest?

Comment: Yes I got it installed. My initial media downloaded from MSDN Subscribers download was not right. I again downloaded it from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28145 and this worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Because SQL Server 2012 isn't out yet, and we're dealing with beta code, this is probably best handled as a support request at Connect.Microsoft.com.  Include all of your logs, and they may be able to diagnose it.

If you do want to pursue it here, include the full build number that you're using, and expect to hear people answer with, "You should try again with the latest release candidate."